# Strange! python datetime.datetime.now() randomly generate unix second and nanosecond timestamp

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, python-datetime

I have deployed a GCP cloud function that updates Firestore time_created and time_updated fields in Firestore. My front-end app first creates these fields in Firestore but my function updates them after processing the documents. A snippet of code below generates the timestamp and I use Firestore update function to update the document. There are a few instances where the fields in Firestore will be updated as a dictionary with keys as "seconds" and "nano_seconds" and their values but not as Timestamp. I have been wondering and trying to track down where the issue is coming from. I suspect datetime.now() sometimes does not generate a timestamp value. Help me if you have an idea or seen something like this before. I have attached a snapshot below. The image attached shows an instance of the wrongly formatted date returned from Firestore to my Front-end.

Documents affected have the field showing as this:

**time_created: {'seconds': 1637694047.0, 'nanoseconds': 580592000.0}**

```
from datetime import datetime

update_doc = {
                u"time_created": datetime.now(),
                u"time_updated": datetime.now()
            }
```

Comment: Please paste text instead of images of text or links to images of text.

Comment: Thanks, I have taken note for future posts. I have updated it with the text. The image showed the result returned from Firestore for the field.

Answer (score 0):

Per @mark-tolonen, please don't include images in questions when it's trivial to copy-and-paste the test. Various reasons.

I experienced a different [issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/issues/4229#issuecomment-925362914) with Firestore timestamps and using the Go SDK. When I read your question, I wondered if the issues were related but, I think not.

That said, you can perform some diagnosis. You can emit the Python `datetime.now()` values of course to ensure you know what's being applied.

You could (!) then use the underlying REST API directly to mimic|repro the calls that your code is making to determine whether the error arises in the API itself or the Python SDK (or your code).

Here's [`projects.databases.documents.patch`](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/patch) which I think underlies the `Set`. There's also [`projects.databases.documents.create`](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/createDocument). In both cases, [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) provides a way for you to try the API methods in the browser and will yield the e.g. `curl` equivalents for you.

> **NOTE**
>
> The API requires a `parent` parameter, defined to be something of the form `projects/{project_id}/databases/{databaseId}/documents`. Replace `project_id` with your Project ID and use `(default)` (with the parenthesis) for the value of `{databaseId}`.

Comment: Thanks for your input @Dazwilkin. Yes, I checked your issue it doesn't seem related. I have included logs to see the values generated from the datetime.now() before the Firestore API is called.

Comment: Did you try making the REST call directly to see whether there's any difference?

Comment: No, the issue only occurs occasionally, once out of a blue moon it occurs, and no way to reproduce that now. So I am now logging document ID and the generated datetime.now() to track anytime it occurs and at that point, I can try the REST call if the correct date format was generated.

Comment: I see. Sounds like a good plan. Good luck!